# Open draft from link with Gmail API in browser

Tags: hyperlink, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to directly open a Gmail draft message, I've tried using a hyperlink formatted like this:

```
"https://mail.google.com/mail/#drafts?compose=" + idDraft
```

However, every time I open the draft message the link takes me to the Draft List. Is it possible with the link or do I have to look for an alternative option?

Comment: Is this the Gmail website you are trying to open it in?  How does this relate to the gmail api exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to open the draft edition window in Gmail, the idea is to redirect the user to the draft edition of the draft with ID = idDraft